# Rails: Use reload! in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reload, rails-models

I'm creating a rails code that could add/remove field of a model.

I've a model Inventory, where I could add a list of fields as below:

```
def update_new_fields
  @fieldnames = params["fieldnames"]

  @fieldnames.each do |fieldname|
    ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column(Inventory, fieldname, :string)
  end    
end
```

To view list of updated fields

```
def index
  reload!
  @fields=Inventory.attribute_names
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
  end
end
```

However, I've got the following error:

```
undefined method `reload!' for #<InventoriesController:0x007fccf70b7720>
```

If I did a reload! in console:

```
2.0.0 :163 >   ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_column(Inventory, "f", :string)
-- remove_column(Inventory(id: integer, name: string, description: string, quatity: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, a: string, b: string, c: string, e: string, f: string), "f", :string)
   (122.9ms)  ALTER TABLE `inventories` DROP `f`
   -> 0.1232s
 => nil
2.0.0 :164 > Inventory.reset_column_information
 => nil
2.0.0 :165 > Inventory.attribute_names
 => ["id", "name", "description", "quatity", "created_at", "updated_at", "a", "b", "c", "e", "f"]
2.0.0 :166 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true
2.0.0 :167 > Inventory.attribute_names
 => ["id", "name", "description", "quatity", "created_at", "updated_at", "a", "b", "c", "e"]
```

It works.

**UPD**

What I've find out is, after foing a "Inventory.reset_column_information", the attribute_names were not updated but the Class information is:

```
2.0.0 :090 > Inventory.reset_column_information
 => nil
2.0.0 :091 > Inventory.attribute_names
 => ["id", "name", "description", "quatity", "created_at", "updated_at", "hello", "next"]
2.0.0 :092 > Inventory
 => Inventory(id: integer, name: string, description: string, quatity: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string)
```

So, the work around I did was:

```
def index
  Inventory.reset_column_information
  tmp = Inventory.new
  @fields=tmp.attribute_names
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
  end
end
```

And finally my field in Inventory is updated.

Comment: Some how when I did this, it works.

`    def index
      Inventory.reset_column_information
      tmp = Inventory.new
      @fields=tmp.attribute_names
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
      end
    end`

Answer (score 2):

Though I wonder why You need this, looks very odd.
But what actually You are looking is to refresh model column information.
It can be done like this:

```
Inventory.reset_column_information
```

**UPD**

Probably it's because the class is cached. You can reload a single class by using `load`

```
load "#{Rails.root}/app/models/inventory.rb"
```

Though it will spit out some warning about redefining. You could use `remove_const` method before actually loading again to avoid warnings.

```
remove_const "Inventory"
load "#{Rails.root}/app/models/inventory.rb"
```

**But beware that doing this may cause errors in production environment. If You use several rails instances, that code would reload the class only on one!** So think twice, maybe there are alternatives how to achieve what You are actually doing. **I strongly not recommend going this path.**

Comment: If you look at the bottom of my message, that's exactly what I've did. But I'd still have a "f" field with Inventory.reset_column_information.